# How to create a qmake function that creates a custom make target?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I know that we have `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` to create new makefile targets, that is used as follows (as seen in http://blog.qt.io/blog/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/):

```
conv.target=convert
conv.input=file.in
conv.output=file.out
conv.commands=convert.sh file.in file.out
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS+=conv
```

In my case, `convert.sh` is used for multiple files and targets. I would like to create a method with arguments (target_name, input_file, output_file), that creates the task for me, so that I don't have to repeat the above lines.

The documentation on qmake is quite lacking, or I haven't found the correct source, but to my understanding, there are two types of functions in qmake: replace and test (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replace-functions) and we can create custom ones using `defineReplace` and `defineTest`.

I have tried:

```
defineTest(createConvertTask) {
    custom.target = $$1
    custom.input = $$2
    custom.output = $$3
    custom.commands = convert.sh $$2 > $$3
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += custom
}
```

but that doesn't really work, as after calling `createConvertTask` multiple times, `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` will just contain multiple copies of the string `custom`.

However, this

```
defineTest(createConvertTask) {
    $$1.target = $$1
    $$1.input = $$2
    $$1.output = $$3
    $$1.commands = convert.sh $$2 > $$3
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $$1
}
```

fails with error `example.pro:2: error: Left hand side of assignment must expand to exactly one word.`

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 1.Option: custom compiler

Use a [custom compiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers) like this:

```
convert.input = LIST_OF_IN_FILES  # note: no $$
convert.output = $${SOME_DIR}/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.ext
convert.commands = convert.sh ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} > $${SOME_DIR}/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.ext

convert.CONFIG += no_link target_predeps
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += convert
```

The variables `${QMAKE_FILE_IN}` contains the *current* input file, same as `${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}` but without extension. Here, the output filenames are generated out of the input files. The `CONFIG` options tell qmake not to add the output files to the objects list and to add them as prerequisites of the main target. Additionally a `make` target `compiler_convert_make_all` will be generated.

Just add files:

```
LIST_OF_IN_FILES += file1 file2
```

and make

```
make compiler_convert_make_all
```

This option also adds all output files to the `clean` target (will be deleted on `make clean`.

#### 2.Option: use `eval()` and `export()`

To use variables as left hand expression you can use the [`eval()` function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#eval-string), that 'Evaluates the contents of the string using qmake syntax rules'.

```
eval($${1}.target = $$1)
```

Since this is done inside a function you need to [`export()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#export-variablename) all variables to the global scope.

```
eval(export($${1}.target))
```

Afterwards add target and export `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` as well:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $${1}
export(QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS)
```

Complete with a [replace function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#replace-functions), the return value will be added to the dependencies of the custom `convert` target:

```
convert.target = convert

defineReplace(createConvertTask) {
    eval($${2}_custom.target = $$2)
    eval($${2}_custom.depends = $$1)
    eval($${2}_custom.commands = convert.sh $$1 > $$2)
    eval(export($${2}_custom.target))
    eval(export($${2}_custom.depends))
    eval(export($${2}_custom.commands))

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $${2}_custom
    export(QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS)
    return($${2}_custom)
 }

 convert.depends += $$createConvertTask(in_file_1, out_file_1)
 convert.depends += $$createConvertTask(in_file_2, out_file_2)

 QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += convert
```

The results in the generated `Makefile`:

```
out_file_1: in_file_1
       convert.sh in_file_1 > out_file_1

out_file_2: in_file_2
       convert.sh in_file_2 > out_file_2

convert: out_file_1 out_file_2
```

This approach is more flexible and can be extended to support the a variable target parameter (here constant `convert`).